# Unable to trac logtout

Tags: authentication, trac

I setup trac on Mac OS X 10.6.5/Apache2.0/wsgi.

I made a wsgi file (hir.wsgi) that points to trac environment as follows.

```
import os

os.environ['TRAC_ENV'] = '/Library/WebServer/Documents/trac/hir'
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/Library/WebServer/Documents/trac/hir/eggs'

import trac.web.main
application = trac.web.main.dispatch_request
```

Apache conf file is added as follows.

```
ScriptAliasMatch ^/hir(.*) "/Library/WebServer/Documents/wsgi/scripts/hir.wsgi$1"
<Location '/hir'>
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Hir"
  AuthUserFile /Library/WebServer/Documents/trac/hir/htpasswd
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Using htpasswd command I added user1, user2.

After relaunching apache, I could login with user1 after giving my id/password, however I can't logout. 
I removed the lines added to conf file, but this time, I can't login with an error message.

```
Trac Error
Authentication information not available.
```

What's wrong with my trac setup? Or is this a cache issue with Safari/IE8?

Comment: You can easily check if it's browser's cache (and it looks like so at the first glance); I haven't got ie/safari at hand, but in ff it is "Tools -> Clear history -> Active logins"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I'm using IE8 with Trac, I have to close all open browser windows after logging out.  Otherwise, something is still cached internally and Trac thinks I'm still logged in.  I don't have that problem in Firefox.  I haven't tried it in Safari, so I can't comment in that regard.

Set your Trac/Apache configuration back like you had it at first and try closing the browser between logout and login.  Clearing the browser cache and deleting any Trac-related cookies might enable you to log in again without closing the window.